# Different Activity starts on installation and lauch app, why?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

I can't explain why my app starts the `MainActivity` on installation, but `StartActivity` on app launch.

To my knowledge, this is managed by the `manifest.xml`. But there I have the `category.LAUNCHER` and `action.MAIN` applied to the `StartActivity` and I want this task always to start first.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity android:name=".StartActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ImageEditActivity"/>
</application>
```

Can someone tell me why the app is behaving like that? Any suggestion and review are welcome. Thank you in advance

Comment: show your code of startactivity

Comment: By "on installation" you mean when you click "Open" on the success page shown by Android after the app gets installed? Or do you mean when you run the app through Android Studio? Can you see if there is any code in `StartActivity` that might be navigating to `MainActivity` based on some condition?

Comment: Much thanks for the advice. Even though the app is not logged on to the erver, due to signOut() method, the variable USER was not == null. So it went on with the MainActivity without doing signIn(). Thanks again!